# What is the surface area of the vitreous humour in contact with aqueous humour?

Tags: human-anatomy, eyes, human-eye

This is a question regarding the anatomy of the human eye, however for my purposes medium sized mammals should do. I am interested in estimating the surface area of the hyaloid membrane of the vitreous humour which has contact with the aqueous humour circulating in the posterior and anterior chamber of a typical human eye.

The surface area in question is highlighted in red in this schematic of the cross section of the human eye.

[image: Anatomical schematic of the human eye.]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Area=πr², d≈2cm (less than maximal d) -> r≈1cm,  thus the area in question is roughly

3.14*1cm*1cm≈3.14cm²

UPD by request (ref):

The vitreous body base middle is at ora serrata (+-2mm), so we should calculate the area at this level. Here is the reference of the diameter:

[image]

from: Basic and Clinical Science Course, Section 02

Comment: Wonderful, thank you very much! I don't suppose you happen to know what the point where the vitreous meets the lens is called?

Comment: @Freeman i've already told you - come back to your prev. question

Comment: @IIan thank you. Thanks for the reference also, that looks like a great book to keep hold of!